# How to programmatically find email associated to a google email (Google Drive)

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Can anyone offer some advice as to how this challenge can be overcome??

**Scenario**
A Google account can have multiple email address associated with. e.g abc@yahoo.com can be an email address associated with a Google account, however if a user has Gmail setup, then the Gmail address becomes the primary email address associated with that account. 
This is particularly relevant to Google Drive, ... where if a user abc@yahoo.com receives a Google Drive 'share' invitation (where the recipient is a non-gmail user) abc@yahoo.com will typically have to create a gmail identity.

**Problem**
Is there a way to check programatically via an API if abc@yahoo.com has a gmail account. 

 (I know its possible to type this manually into the Google Drive share screen), ..is there a programatic way of doing it?

Comment: I don't think there's an exposed programmtic way to do this. The closest thing I could find is this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40560?hl=en